# Json file data into kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

How to insert json file data into kafka topic using kafka-console-producer?
Can each json data set be stored as a message?

example-

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Lindt",
  "email": "jlindt@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

If you use this command -

```
cat sampledata.json|kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic  stream-test-topic
```

Each line is taken as a separate message.

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

ps-

The topic is being read by Elastic search. Sample json message file -

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Lindt",
  "email": "jlindt@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.2.3.4"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Peter",
  "last_name": "Friz",
  "email": "Friz3@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "4.5.6.7"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Dell",
  "last_name": "Chang",
  "email": "Dellc@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "8.9.10.11"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "first_name": "Lolita",
  "last_name": "John",
  "email": "LolitaJ@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Female",
  "ip_address": "12.13.14.15"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "first_name": "Pele",
  "last_name": "Wang",
  "email": "Pele@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "16.17.18.19"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "first_name": "Rene",
  "last_name": "Charm",
  "email": "Rene3@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "20.21.22.23"
}]
```

Comment: What is your message delimiter? SImply a new JSON object? Where's the JSON originate from?

Comment: Updated my question with sample json file.

Comment: So you have a file with a single JSON array, and you want to explode that array into individual messages? Is that right?

Comment: And; where is this data coming from? Almost certainly a better pattern here would be for the process constructing the JSON array and writing that file to instead just send it straight to Kafka

Comment: Yes , each json data should be splitted into a separate message . Ex- single message like - {
"id": 1,
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Lindt",
  "email": "jlindt@gmail.com",
  "gender": "Male",
  "ip_address": "1.2.3.4"
}

Comment: 6 individual messages for this json data set.

Comment: where is this data coming from? - This is random data we have put in the topic using kafka-console-producer through a json file . We want this topic to be read by  elastic seach .. (a simple poc)

Comment: "This is random data we have put in the topic using kafka-console-producer through a json file " … haha, ok, right, let's work this back. You're wanting to build an application or pipeline, that streams data to Elasticsearch, and you want to do so via Kafka. Now the data that's going to Elasticsearch, where is it going to come from? I don't mean how are you building your prototype, I mean, where does that data come from? Why are you writing it to a file and not directly to Kafka with a native client library or REST proxy?

Comment: If you literally want to take some dummy data from a file and shove it into a topic for testing purposes then just break it out of the array, and put one object on each line. That's all.

Answer (score 27):

From point of view of Kafka each message is array of bytes. 
It's up to client's application (producer, consumer, etc), how it treats it.
Kafka Producer, Consumer uses Deserializer, Serializer to transform from/to Array of bytes to/from business object (String, POJO)

Issue with which you are facing is way that Kafka Console producer read message from standard input.
Be default it uses `LineMessageReader`, which treats each line as new message. You can implement your own, or before sending translate each new line character in json to some other white space.

For example you can use following command:

`jq -rc . sampledata.json | kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic  stream-test-topic`

Comment: Using jq -rc is brilliant in its simplicity! If you don't need to validate the jason, having it on a single line is enough for the kafka-console-producer to write it as a single message. It certainly worked for me.

Comment: This should be the best-rated reply, as it perfectly answers to the original issue: how to pass a multi-line json to a Kafka producer.

Comment: #unixway is always my falourite!

Answer (score 21):

If you have JSON messages in the file, you can use following way to write in the kafka topic:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic user-timeline < samplerecords.json
```

Kafka producers reads the messages line by line using default `LineMessageReader`. Default Key and value serializers are `StringSerializer`. It will not validate whether there is a proper json or not, instead consider as raw string object as publish to a kafka topic. But if you want to validate you can define below configuration in console-producer command.

```
key.serializer
value.serializer
```

Example :

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testTopic--property value.serializer=custom.class.serialization.JsonSerializer
```

At the consumer side, you can do the similar approach. Use JsonDeserializer to read the data.

Comment: I found this one did not work for me, even though i also tried to use key.serializer.

Comment: maybe it works with single-line file but with multiline json file every line becomes separate message

Answer (score 5):

I am new to Kafka as well, and had the same use case as you. After some R&D I found a brief answer that may help you. You can write something like below:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic blogpost
{"title":"The Matrix","year":1999,"cast":["Keanu Reeves","Laurence Fishburne","Carrie-Anne Moss","Hugo Weaving","Joe Pantoliano"],"genres":["Science Fiction"]}.
```

For a more detailed look [click here](https://gist.github.com/hpgrahsl/8c145bf12c3b98d8b5146632bddc6d6d)

Answer (score 4):

This answer will be helpful for those who are looking out for kafka console producer to send json data whose key and value is json.

Command

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --property parse.key=true --property key.separator="&" --topic test-topic
```

JSON

```
{"key":"1"}&{"name":"emp1","sent_at":1625519962875}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the Json to the topic:

```
echo '{"test": 1}' | bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic
```