# Sending JSON to a Kafka Cluster?

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I'm a Kafka-beginner and i just wanted to confirm a potential pipeline i'm looking to implement:

If i have a web app that generates JSON data, do i need to set up (inside of the app logic itself) a serializer to serialize the JSON data to bytes, so i can send it in a Kafka stream through my Kafka Cluster?

Then, i wish to consume it from the stream, convert it back to JSON and upload it to AWS S3.
Is that being done at the Kafka Connect (S3 sink) level?
How does the sink pass the JSON to S3 then? How does it work "under the hood"? (i couldn't find a high-level overview anywhere)

Lastly - i know i can implement a Kafka Cluster using AWS MSK. Would i have to also spin up a worker node to stream the data from Kafka to my S3? Is there no way to transfer data from MSK to S3?

Comment: If you don't define a serde Kafka will use the String serde and send the json as string. It is better to define the json serde. Your web app will do the job of the kafka prodcer  command line demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673559/2096986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do i need to set up (inside of the app logic itself) a serializer

All Kafka clients require a serializer, yes. Spring and Confluent both have JsonSerializer classes, or you can pick your own JSON library and use the String or ByteArray serializers directly

Kafka Connect uses Confluent's JSON deserializer, though, so maybe best use its serializer for best support. Connect and the S3 sink are both open source, if you want to dig into the specifics

Yes, you need to run your own infrastructure to use Kafka Connect with MSK. ECS or EKS would be easiest, depending on your experience with containers